# Badge for being included in the newsletter?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, newsletter

A "Published" badge for being a "question/answer of the week" in the weekly newsletter.

It should be at least silver, and maybe gold since there are only 52 per year.
To be awarded retrospectively, of course.

Yet another badge? Maybe not - it would promote the newsletter, which many don't realise exists. I can recall congratulating a 150K+ user on being this week's best answer, and he replied "what newsletter?" - he had no idea.

At least if there's a badge for it, folks would be more likely to take an interest in it.

Comment: What is this newsletter you're talking about?

Comment: @Amber, I think Bohemian is referring to site based newsletters.

Comment: If the goal is to expose the newsletter, then a bronze badge for signing up for the site's newsletter would suffice I think. Additional badges for being published in them doesn't seem to encourage any behavior that's not already encouraged.

Answer (score 4):

You already get a badge for a good question or answer.

I do agree it's an obscure feature. I can't find anything about it on the help pages and you only seem to be able to subscribe to a newsletter by visiting your own network wide profile.

Comment: Yes, the badges are indeed there for nice, good etc questions and answers.. if anything, a 'Published' badge, should it be accepted ought to be bronze - but are on the fence regarding whether it gets awarded once or for each time.

Comment: @UV-D bronze??? Published posts typically have scores of 70+ reached within the week (you could check the algorithm). bronze seems a bit light - you get that for 10 votes.